# ADFS Alternative questions

Tags: adfs, saml

We had (Before it went belly up) an ADFS server that was simply doing a translation  from SAML 2.0 to WSFED (My end point software can not take in SAML only WSFED).

My question is, what are the alternatives to ADFS to do this translation.

Does Azure AD have this capability?  I've done some research but really high level it does not seem to be my solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any IDP that can act as a R-STS can do this.

Examples are Auth0 and identityserver.

A R-STS is an IDP that can sit in the middle of a chain e.g.

App --> R-STS --> STS.

Azure AD is not a R-STS and so can't do this.